# LED's Headlights turning off and on

Tags: electrical, headlight, led

I recently purchased a pair of Zdatt H13 9008 LED headlights for my 08 Dodge Ram 3500. After they warm up 3-4 minutes they turn off and on repeatedly. What am I missing and how do I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are they overheating, Is there sufficient cooling? Is the supply sufficient?

Comment: i can hear the Fans working and when I touch the housing it isn't that hot yet. I installed 2 new batteries last week and a new alternator early summer

Comment: I didnt drive it. It was dark when I installed them.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did you have the engine running above idle, theses bulbs are sensitive to low voltage... They can flicker or not light if below 13V or so...

Comment: No Solar Mike I did not. what if you're sitting at an idle somewhere? It would suck if they went out in front of the police.   lol, What can I do to prevent it if that is what's going on?